# Angular - Combine input from button click with data from modal?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to web development and have started making my own site. A friend of mine showed me the basics of angular, so i am trying to use that. My idea is to create an inventory of your household items (primarily food) that a user can use (when they cook something) and then add to their shopping list, and then buy it, which would increase the amount they have of that item.

Anyway, my problems is this : I have a list of foods (Meat, Milk, Flour). Below each food there are 2 buttons - **Use**, and **Add to shopping list**. What i want to have happen is the following : When a user clicks the "Use" belonging to a certain food (let's say Flour) a modal will pop up, asking the user how many percentage of the food they used.

Once the user inputs a valid amount, the data (food + amount used) is passed to a function which will handle the updating of the data in the backend. What is the "angular" way to do this? I've come up with a solution which basically goes like this -

Clicking "Use" will trigger a function, passing along the associated foodname. I save this foodname in a variable, $scope.actualFood. Then, i display a modal asking the user for what percentage was used. I should then be able to (when the user clicks "Okay") be able to extract that percentage from the form using the form ID. Then, i'll have both the food and the percentage used. But i feel like this is a very inefficient way to to this.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated! I've attached the HTML for the food list below for extra clarification

```
 <div id="foodDataList" class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3" ng-repeat="food in message track by $index">
                        <div class="card" ng-click="callsomething(food)">
                            <img width="100%" ng-src="{{food.imageURL}}" alt="Food icon"/>
                            <div class="inside-of-img" style="text-align: center;">
                            </div>
                    </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4 class="card-title"> <strong>{{food.foodName}} <strong></h4>
                            <h4>You have this much:</h4>
                            <progress value="70" max="100">70%</progress>
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <button type="button" ng-click="useFood(food.foodName)" class="btn btn-danger">Use</button>
                                <button type="button" ng-click="addToShoppingList(food.foodName)" class="btn btn-primary">Add To Shopping List</button>
                             </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```